# Issues when using with bluetooth and A-Frame

Tags: google-chrome, aframe

Currently utilising A-Frame 1.0.4 (will consider updating not sure if it's necessary). Host system is Android running Chrome 89.

I have 2 independent scripts working one with bluetooth and one with a-frame. When i merge them chrome throws an error stating Web Bluetooth is not supported and will no longer attempt to connect to the device.

Now this can't be directly true as i have them working independently on the same host/browser, is there any known collisions when trying to get the two to work together? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears after chasing down the issue, a hard restart of the browser appears to have cleared the issue. Unclear to the exact root cause.